Room database reset after app close and reopen
I created a Compose app with a room database and flows, which is loading data from an assets database. Then I add favorites and more stuff. It works and stores favorites until I close the app and reopen it. Then, all favorites are lost and the database seems to be the same as the assets database. Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?
the database:
@Database(entities = [Airport::class, Favorite::class], version = 1)
abstract class FlightsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun flightsDao(): FlightsDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: FlightsDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): FlightsDatabase {
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    FlightsDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database"
                )
                    .createFromAsset("database/flight_search.db")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                    .also { Instance = it}
            }
        }
    }
}

the repository initialization:
class DefaultAppContainer(private val context: Context) : AppContainer {
    override val flightRepository: FlightsRepository by lazy {
        OfflineFlightsRepository(FlightsDatabase.getDatabase(context).flightsDao())
    }
    override val userPreferencesRepository = UserPreferencesRepository(context.dataStore)
}

the repository:
interface FlightsRepository {
    fun getAllAirports(): Flow<List<Airport>>
    fun getAirportsByIatOrName(text: String): Flow<List<Airport>>
    fun getAllDifferentAirports(id: Int): Flow<List<Airport>>
    fun getFavorites(): Flow<List<Favorite>>
    suspend fun insertFavorite(favorite: Favorite)
}

class OfflineFlightsRepository(private val flightsDao: FlightsDao) : FlightsRepository {
    override fun getAllAirports(): Flow<List<Airport>> {
        return flightsDao.getAllAirports()
    }

    override fun getAirportsByIatOrName(text: String): Flow<List<Airport>> {
        return flightsDao.getAirportsByIatOrName(text)
    }

    override fun getAllDifferentAirports(id: Int): Flow<List<Airport>> {
        return flightsDao.getAllDifferentAirports(id)
    }

    override fun getFavorites(): Flow<List<Favorite>> {
        return flightsDao.getFavorites()
    }

    override suspend fun insertFavorite(favorite: Favorite) {
        val foundFavorite = flightsDao.getFavoriteByIATAS(favorite.departureCode, favorite.destinationCode)

        if (foundFavorite != null && foundFavorite.first() != null) {
            val favorite = foundFavorite.first()
            flightsDao.deleteFavorite(favorite)
        } else {
            flightsDao.insertFavorite(favorite)
        }
    }
}

the dao:
@Dao
interface FlightsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM airport ORDER BY passengers DESC")
    fun getAllAirports(): Flow<List<Airport>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM airport WHERE iata_code LIKE '%'||:text||'%' OR name LIKE '%'||:text||'%' ORDER BY passengers DESC")
    fun getAirportsByIatOrName(text: String): Flow<List<Airport>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM airport WHERE id NOT LIKE :id ORDER BY passengers DESC")
    fun getAllDifferentAirports(id: Int): Flow<List<Airport>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite")
    fun getFavorites(): Flow<List<Favorite>>

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE departure_code = :departureCode AND destination_code = :destinationCode)")
    suspend fun checkIfFavoriteExists(departureCode: String, destinationCode: String): Boolean

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite WHERE departure_code = :departureCode AND destination_code = :destinationCode")
    fun getFavoriteByIATAS(departureCode: String, destinationCode: String): Flow<Favorite>?

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertFavorite(favorite: Favorite)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteFavorite(favorite: Favorite)
}


Well finally it was solved doing a check to see if a previous database is already created and only call createFromAssets if not. Can't believe google didn't wrote that in the documentation, they just wrote that you must use createFromAsset bug don't tell that you can check if previous db exists (and how to do it) and call it only if not exist. I assumed that room automatically checked that. They should improve the documentation.
fun getDatabase(context: Context): FlightsDatabase {
    return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        val dbFile = context.getDatabasePath("app_database")
        val builder = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            FlightsDatabase::class.java,
            "app_database"
        )

        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            builder.createFromAsset("database/flight_search.db")
        }

        builder
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
            .also { Instance = it }
    }
}


Actually, createFromAsset will only write the database file into the internal app database if it does not exist yet, as you had expected. The problem lies in the combination of createFromAsset and fallbackToDestructiveMigration.
The documentation has a chapter about migration with prepackaged databases:

Prepackaged database files can also change the way your Room database handles fallback migrations. Ordinarily, when destructive migrations are enabled and Room must perform a migration without a migration path, Room drops all tables in the database and creates an empty database with the specified schema for the target version. However, if you include a prepackaged database file with the same number as the target version, Room attempts to populate the newly recreated database with the contents of the prepackaged database file after performing the destructive migration.

For some reason, Room thinks that a migration is happening each time the app is opened, which might be the actual bug here. This has also been reported on stackoverflow several times (#1, #2, #3). The suggested solutions are to either conditionally execute createFromAsset as you already did or to remove fallbackToDestructiveMigration and always provide explicit migrations instead so that the fallback destructive migration will never be needed.
Please consider to report this at the Google Issue Tracker, as we still don't know why Room thinks a migration happened in the first place.
